# get img alt of a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using `dropzone.js`. Is there a way I can get the `filename` on the click event of `removefile`? I was thinking of getting the `filename` from `dz-filename`'s `IMG` alt and remove the image from the database and server. If there's another way that'd be great too!

But this is what I have and it gives me undefined as the name:

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">  
  <div class="dz-details">    
    <div class="dz-filename">
      <span data-dz-name="">d24baa48eb1b8ed17755796425141fdc.jpg</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size="">
      <strong>9</strong> KiB
    </div>    
    <img data-dz-thumbnail="" alt="d24baa48eb1b8ed17755796425141fdc.jpg" src="/images/thumbnail/d24baa48eb1b8ed17755796425141fdc.jpg">
  </div>
  <a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>
</div>
```

I also tried: `siblings`, `find` and `closest`.

```
this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
  var name = $(this).parent(".dz-image-preview")
               .siblings(".dz-details").children("img").attr("alt");
  alert(name);
});
```

Comment: Upvoted comment for the multiple meanings ]:)

Answer (score 0):

From that bit of your code, I believe `$(this)` is something inside `<div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">`. So from that assumption you can get the `alt` by doing this:

```
$(this).parents(".dz-image-preview").find("img").attr("alt");
```